# Merging two created histograms in order to compare them

Tags: r

I would like to compare election results (Percentatge.of.Votes) of two different candidates by states and plot them in one graphic.

For that I compiled the following:

```
swing.obama = filter(swing.states, Candidate == "Barack Obama")

swing.romney = filter(swing.states, Candidate != "Barack Obama")

par(mfrow=c(2,1))

ro.swing = barplot(swing.romney$Percentatge.of.Votes, names.arg = swing.romney$State.or.district,
                    col = "red2", main = "Results by State - Mitt Romney")

ob.swing = barplot(swing.obama$Percentatge.of.Votes, names.arg = swing.obama$State.or.district,
                   col = "darkblue", main = "Results by State - Barack Obama")
```

Here you can see both results in histograms side by side.

Results by State:

[image]

How can "merge" the two files in order to get the blue and red bars side by side?

Comment: Please consider formatting you questions

Answer (score 1):

Please test this `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(swing.states, 
       aes(State.or.district, Percentatge.of.Votes, fill = Candidate)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
labs(title = "Results by state",
     x = "State/district",
     y = "Votes, %")
```